# Upload de imagens com adição de elemento na imagem

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, upload, image

Olá preciso fazer um upload onde, na imagem, o cliente poderá adicionar um elemento visual para demarcar algo. Precisarei de algo via javascript para fazer a interação visual antes do upload(parte mais simples).

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Por exemplo, na imagem abaixo eu peguei a foto de um quarto qualquer e adicionei uma seta apontando para um elemento do quarto. Isso é o que eu preciso fazer, alguém pode me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Atualização]

Baseado na solução porposta por algumas pessoas, inclusive pelo Valdir Psr que mandou uma ótima solução, pesquisando um pouco mais encontrei uma lib chamada Fabric.js e consegui fazer uma implementação que considerei mais simples.

[Solução]

Para quem interessar segue o projeto exemplo que criei no github: https://github.com/alessandrosales/image-editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das formas de fazer isso é utilizando `canvas` e os eventos de `Drag And Drop`, nativos, do `HTML5`.

[**Demonstração**](http://stackoverflow.rickcds.com/275596/)
[**Download do Projeto**](https://gist.github.com/valdeir2000/c6a322083fa2eb1ac096b008fe7836cc)

#### Arrastando e soltando um objeto na tela

Para utilizar a opção `draggable` é bastante simples. Basta definir o atributo `draggable="true"` no elemento que será arrastado. No caso a seta.

```
<div id="img">
    <img id="main" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350?text=Clique+para+carregar+uma+imagem" />
    <img id="arrow" draggable="true" src="arrow.png" />
    <canvas style="display:none"></canvas>
</div>
```

Agora só precisamos capturar o valor da posição em relação ao elemento.

Na função `ondragstart`, nós capturamos de onde o elemento "partiu".

```
imgArrow.addEventListener("dragstart", (ev) => {
    /* Capturamos o valor da propriedade `left` e `top` do CSS */
    let left = ev.target.style.getPropertyValue("left") || 0;
    let top = ev.target.style.getPropertyValue("top") || 0;

    /* Subtraímos a posição do elemento em relação a posição dele na tela e salvamos para consultar posteriormente. */
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("left", parseInt(left) - ev.clientX);
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("top", parseInt(top) - ev.clientY);
});
```

Na função `ondragover`, nós validamos a ação `drop`.

```
imgArea.addEventListener("dragover", (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Na função `ondrop`, nós iremos capturar a posição `x` e `y` de onde o objeto foi soltado e iremos capturar os valores setados anteriormente para calcular a nova posição do objeto.

```
imgArea.addEventListener("drop", (ev) => {
    /* Capturamos os valores "x" e "y" setado anteriormente */
    let left = ev.dataTransfer.getData("left") || 0;
    let top = ev.dataTransfer.getData("top") || 0;

    /* Somamos o valor setado anteriormente com a nova posição do objeto em relação a tela */
    imgArrow.style.left = parseInt(left) + ev.clientX;
    imgArrow.style.top = parseInt(top) + ev.clientY;
});
```

Pronto! Já temos o efeito de arrastar e soltar a seta.

#### Salvando a nova imagem.

Agora vamos trabalhar com o `canvas` para manipular nossa nova imagem. Para isso nós iremos utilizar apenas o `context` e o método `drawImage` do elemento citado.

```
/* Aqui setamos a largura e altura do canvas */
this.canvas.width = imgMain.width;
this.canvas.height = imgMain.height;

/* Capturamos o contexto */
let ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");

/*
 * Aqui nós desenhamos a imagem principal no canvas.
 * Adiciona a imagem na posição x=0 e y=0 juntamente 
 * com a largura e altura da imagem
 */
ctx.drawImage(imgMain, 0, 0, imgMain.width, imgMain.height)

/*
 * Aqui nós desenhamos a seta no canvas.
 * Adiciona a imagem na posição definidos no `css` (left e top)
 * juntamente com a largura e altura da imagem
 */
ctx.drawImage(imgArrow, parseInt(imgArrow.style.left), parseInt(imgArrow.style.top), imgArrow.width, imgArrow.height);
```

Pronto. Finalizado mais uma parte.

#### Enviando a imagem para o servidor.

Nesse último passo também não há dor de cabeça. Basta utilizarmos o método `toBlob` para capturar o arquivo e `XHR` para enviarmos para o servidor.

```
canvas.toBlob(blob => {
    let form = new FormData();
    form.append("file", blob);

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function(result) { alert( result.target.responseText ); }
    xhr.open("POST", "upload.php", true);
    xhr.send(form);
});
```

#### Facilitando as coisas

Bem, eu acabei fazendo uma classe bem simples. Basta baixa no link de download e utilizar da seguinte forma:

```
const imgArea = document.querySelector("#img");
const imgMain = document.querySelector("#img #main");
const imgArrow = document.querySelector("#img #arrow");
const btnDownload = document.querySelector("#btnDownload");

new DragAndDrop(imgArea, imgMain, imgArrow, {
    arrowHeight: 100, //Altura da seta
    arrowWidth: 100,  //Largura da seta
    btnDownload: btnDownload,  //Botão de Download

    //Eventos
    dragStart: () => {
        console.log("Start");
    },
    dragOver: () => {
        console.log("Over");
    },
    dragDrop: () => {
        console.log("Drop")
    }
});
```

[**Demonstração**](http://stackoverflow.rickcds.com/275596/)
[**Download do Projeto**](https://gist.github.com/valdeir2000/c6a322083fa2eb1ac096b008fe7836cc)

Comment: Olá Valdeir, muito obrigado é exatamente o que eu preciso. Excelente!!!

Comment: Olá Valdir, baseado na sua solução eu fiz uma implementação utilizando Fabric.js: https://github.com/alessandrosales/image-editor

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, não sabia para onde ir quanto lancei a pergunta hahaah ;)